# google places searchbox element change

Tags: google-maps

I have a list of items and each of them has input field with places autocomplete. I'm using Google maps searchbox api for this. The question is how to create one instance of Searchbox and use it for all the inputs (on focus change for example change the element Searchbox attached to)

```
var search = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(element1);
search.someMethodToSwitchElement(element2);
```